# Manter o dado do campo conforme select

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
    // Dentro do arquivo somar.js
    <script>
    function soma(){
    if(document.getElementById('QtdAcomodacaoSingle').options[0].selected == false){
     TextoAcos = (QtdAco == 1)?("passageiro"):("passageiros");           
                 document.getElementById("alterar").innerHTML = QtdAcos + " " + TextoAcos;
    ......
    }
    }
    </script>

    // Página index.php
    <select name="QtdAcomodacaoS" id="QtdAcomodacaoSingle" class="form-control" style="width:130px" onchange="soma()">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    </option>
<div id="alterar" style="text-align: center; ">---</div>
```

Quando seleciono a quantidade de acomodações, automaticamente aparece o número selecionado na div alterar. Até aqui tudo bem. Porém eu quero manter as informações no formulário que foram cadastradas. Consigo em todos os campos, porém como eu faria para que esse efeito de selecionar um número aparecesse na div alterar, funcionasse depois de trazer esses resultados no php? Tentei dessa forma:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['Ativo'] == false){ ?>
       <div id="alterar" style="text-align: center; ">---</div>
       <?php }else{ 
              echo $visualizarS->QtdPax; 
            } 
       ?>
```

Quando faço dessa forma, a div alterar fica presa dentro da validação da Sessão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta dessa forma:

```
<div id="alterar" style="text-align: center; ">
    <?php 
    echo ($_SESSION['Ativo'] == false) ? '---' : $visualizarS->QtdPax; 
    ?>
</div>
```